# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function that is not in a class

Tags: php, function, include, undefined, fatal-error

So i am working on some code and have come across this error and its starting to bug me a little as i cant find out what is wrong

i have 2 files `main.php` and that includes `functions.php` now in the main file i have the following code

```
<?php
   include "functions.php";
   $NAME = GET_USER_NAME();
?>
```

That is all thats in the main file now in the functions file i have the following code

```
<?php
    function GET_USER_NAME() {
      return 'bob';
    }
    function GET_USER_AGE() {
      return '5';
    }
 ?>
```

now when i try and open main in my browser i get the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function GET_USER_NAME() in /var/www/html/main.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/main.php on line 3
```

i know the file is being included properly as i can run the function

```
GET_USER_AGE();
```

from the main file and it returns 5

Comment: Do not use such [method names](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/).

Answer (score 0):

The only possible solutions to your problem are :

- A typo in the function called in the main, which is not the exact same as in your included file (case sensitivity ?)
- The include references a file which is not the one you want (but has one of the 2 desired functions)

And also yes, as @Markus-Zeller says, don't use method names like that, as stated here :  https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#1-overview

Comment: no spelling issues so i have no idea what was going on reinstalled php & light http it is now working with the same files.


as for the method names there is nothing wrong with them & usage of them in all caps is perfectly fine & dose not affect how the code runs the use of camalCase is simply for astetic purposes to make the code more readable & understandable by other developers 


in this situation that dose not matter as i am the only developer working on the code & as someone with dyslexia all caps make it far more easy for my self to read & understand compared to lower case

Comment: Strange you had to reinstall, configuration maybe ? Can't figure out.  
You can define the rules for what suits you better, it's your project, and as you wrote you're the only developper.  
Just keep in mind that if one day you work with other developpers, they will surely use camelCase to name their functions. And in order to maintain consistency in code, they most likely won't accept your function naming convention.